# How to solve JRE synchronisation issue between Websphere Application server and IIM

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere-7

I am trying to import a Websphere Application server version 7.0.0.27, which was installed using standalone installer, into IBM Installation manager for installing the "WebSphere Application Server V7 Feature Pack for OSGi Applications and Java Persistence API 2.0". The readme which came with the feature pack details the steps to import an installation of WAS 7 into IIM. But when I am entering the WAS installation path into IIM, it is throwing the following error.

"The software development kit version is not the same as the IBM Websphere Application server version. Use another tool, such as the update installer for Websphere software to synchronize versions"

I am guessing this is because of version mismatch between the jre used by WAS and the jre used by the IIM, the details of which are given below:

IIM Jre:

```
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pwi3260sr9fp1-20110208_03(SR9 FP1))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Windows 7 x86-32 jvmwi3260sr9-2011020
3_74623 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20110203_074623
JIT  - r9_20101028_17488ifx3
GC   - 20101027_AA)
JCL  - 20110203_01
```

WAS JRE:

```
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pwa6460sr9fp2ifix-20110727_01(SR9 FP2+IV0
3622))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Windows 7 amd64-64 jvmwa6460sr9-20110
619_85080 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20110619_085080
JIT  - r9_20101028_17488ifx12
GC   - 20101027_AA)
JCL  - 20110727_07
```

I have updated IIM to the latest available(1.7.2) but still getting the error. What might be the solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Download the SDK 7.0.0.27 and install it via UPDI then apply import.
SDK fix pack download: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24033882